# Removing matching text from line

Tags: sed

I have a example cut down from a log file.

```
112 172.172.172.1#50912 (ssl.bing.com):
```

I would like some how to remove the # and numbers after and (): from the url.

Would like the result.

```
112 172.172.172.1 ssl.bing.com
```

Here is the sed oneliner I have been working on.

```
cat newdns.log | sed -e 's/.*query: //' | cut -f 1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2 > old.log
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed 's/#[0-9]*//;s/(\(.*\)):$/\1/' filename
```

or, in a single substitution:

```
sed 's/#[0-9]* *(\(.*\)):$/ \1/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/#[^ ]+|[():]//g'
```

```
$ echo '112 172.172.172.1#50912 (ssl.bing.com):' | sed -r 's/#[^ ]+|[():]//g'
112 172.172.172.1 ssl.bing.com
```